# Using SnapsToDevicePixels in OnRender

Tags: wpf, rendering

I have a class derived from `FrameworkElement` in which I override the `OnRender` method to draw several lines.  I would like the behaviour of `SnapsToDevicePixels` to work with my primitive control, what is the best way to go about doing this?.

I am aware of `GuidelineSet`s and how to use them, but looking at some examples of elements over at [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) they were not used and I saw nothing that takes into account `SnapsToDevicePixels` in the `OnRender` overrides.  Only a few portions of `UIElement` does anything with it in the `Arrange` method, yet the property works on `Rectangle`s.

I feel as though checking the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property is `true` and then pushing a `GuidelineSet` onto the `drawingContext` would be the naïve approach and I had thought (hoped) there was a better way to incorporate it.

Is this the case? If so, How should I design my `OnRender` methods to utilise `SnapsToDevicePixels`?